# Is ToArray() optimized for arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, resharper

ReSharper suggested to enumerate an `IEnumerable<T>` to a list or array since I had *"possible multiple enumerations of `IEnumerable<T>`"*.

The automatic code re-factoring suggested has some optimization built in to see whether `IEnumerable<T>` already is an array before calling `ToArray()`.

```
var list = source as T[] ?? source.ToArray();
```

- Isn't this optimization already built-in the original LINQ method?
- If not, what would be the motivation not to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, there is no such optimization. If source is `ICollection`, then it will be copied to new array. Here is code of `Buffer<T>` struct, which used by `Enumerable` to create array:

```
internal Buffer(IEnumerable<TElement> source)
{    
    TElement[] array = null;
    int length = 0;
    ICollection<TElement> is2 = source as ICollection<TElement>;
    if (is2 != null)
    {
         length = is2.Count;
         if (length > 0)
         {
             array = new TElement[length]; // create new array
             is2.CopyTo(array, 0); // copy items
         }
    }
    else // we don't care, because array is ICollection<TElement>

    this.items = array;
}
```

And here is `Enumerable.ToArray()` method:

```
public static TSource[] ToArray<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    Buffer<TSource> buffer = new Buffer<TSource>(source);
    return buffer.ToArray(); // returns items
}
```

Comment: Thank you, dotPeek didn't seem to show me the source code. Any input on the second part of the question? _"If not, what would be the motivation not to do so?"_

Comment: @StevenJeuris well, for arrays you can do that. But I can't give a scenario when I'd like to call `ToArray()` for array :) If you do some LINQ query, then result will be `IEnumerable` which is not array.

Comment: Calling `.ToArray()` makes a _copy_ of the source. If you want to copy an array, that's one way to do it. Like `T[] someArr = XXX; T[] copyArr = someArr.ToArray();` Of course you don't **have** to use an extension method for that, but there's nothing wrong with doing it. If you say (like in the question): `var list = source as T[] ?? source.ToArray();`, and after that say `list[0] = new T();`, then if `source` is already a `T[]`, you will modify the original, while if `source` is something else, like a `List<T>`, you will modify a copy.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen very good catch about creating copy, didn't though about that!